# Seasonal Time Series

Tags: time-series, self-study

Suppose $ X_t = (\alpha + \beta{t})S_{t} + e_{t}$.

Define $C_{12} = 1 - B^{12}$ as the backshift operator.

Assume $ S_{t}=S_{t-12}$ for all $t$.

Assume that $e_{t}$ is white noise.

Is $C*X_{t}$ stationary? If not, give a different backshift operator that makes the series stationary.

When I solved this I got: $E[CX_{t}] = 12*\beta*S_{t}$ which is a constant.

Also I got that

$$var(CX_{t})= var((\alpha + \beta{t})S_{t} + e_{t} - (\alpha*S_{t-12} + \beta*t*S_{t} - S_{t}*12*\beta + e_{t-12})) $$
$$ = var(e_t +12 \beta S_t - e_{t-12}) = cov(e_{t},e_{t+12})$$

I use $S_{t}$ since $S_{t} = S_{t-12}$ for all $t$.

Apparently this is wrong as the series is nonstationary using this backshift operator.

What am I doing wrong? How is this series nonstationary and how do I find the correct backshift operator that makes it stationary?

Comment: Your variance looks like it has a typo, or rather two typos.

Comment: What do you mean by $var(e_{t},e_{t+12})$?

Comment: It's the covariance between the white noise at time t and the white noise at time t+12. And this obviously is not dependent on t only on the lag between t and t+12.  I don't how I can make myself more clear

Comment: How do you get $var((\alpha + \beta{t})S_{t} + e_{t} - (\alpha*S_{t+12} + \beta*t*S_{t} + S_{t}*12*\beta + e_{t+12})) = cov(e_{t},e_{t+12})$?

Comment: After differencing, you get $var(e_{t} -S_{t}12\beta - e_{t+12})$ and this is constant for all t. I realize my mistake My notation was bad.

Comment: Your mathematics apparently still contains several errors. Watch your signs. What do you get when you do $B^{12} e_t$?

Comment: $B^{12}e^{t} = e_{t-12}$

Comment: Right, so where did all the $e_{t+12}$'s come from?  (the mystery of the homework tag is solved by the way - @whuber just now mapped it to `self-study`)

Comment: Even after the changes, the variance still does not depend on t

Comment: See my edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect the changed question:

$$C_{12}X_{t} = 12 \beta S_{t-12} + e_t - e_{t-12}$$

The distribution of $e_t - e_{t-12}$ is not changing with time, but note that the mean *is* changing with time, since $S_t$ isn't constant.

To figure out what operator would make the original series stationary, consider what you'd do to  $12 \beta S_{t-12} + e_t - e_{t-12}$ to make it stationary

Comment: What convinces you that the solution is correct?

Comment: "I lost points" only indicates that the person allocating points thought it was non stationary. Do you have some convincing *explanation* as to why you should agree? (NB: Are you sure you transcribed everything correctly? Please double check, especially your variance.)

Comment: et is white noise. I think my explanation makes sense. The variance simply depends on the lag and the mean is constant since St = St-1

Comment: That's really weird. Thanks for clarifying my understanding of my problem. All the information I gave you was correct.

Comment: It's always possible I've made an error too (I do that sometimes), but in this case I doubt it. Mistakes creep in to even the best-run courses. Can you get a worked solution?

Comment: I actually edited the question. $S_{t} = S_{t-12}$ for all $t$.

Comment: @phil Interestingly, I thought that was likely what was intended from the start; it was one of several reasons (the other main one being the additivity of thw error term since either might have been relevant to nonstationarity) that I kept saying to check. Note that this changes the answer significantly.

Comment: I have edited my answer